# How to fix container tag to move it up when body tag has padding that can't be changed

Tags: html, css

I have a body tag with padding-top set to 100px which can't be change rest of the application relies on this setting. I need to move my container up so that you don't have to scroll to view the whole login page.

I have tried margin-top: 0; in the container

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 100px;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

#container {
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#container {
position: relative;
margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may work..

**css**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removes padding behaviour on widths */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:-100px
}
```